# LoadRunner and critical error in the attachment handler module.

Tags: file-upload, jvm, out-of-memory, loadrunner

Running a performance test that uploads typically 3,5 MB pdf documents I run into the following error Message in the Controller:

```
Error: Internal Error: Critical error in attachments handler module. Error details: JVM run out of memory.
```

I Guess this has to do With LoadRunner running out of JVM memory doing the file handling With the scripts attachments.

Due to this I have a hypothesis that by increasing the JVM in LoadRunner this probelm could be solved. Is there a way to "give" the loadgenerator/cotroller (we use it as both) more JVM memory?

Comment: Could you please specify the LR version, the OS version and bitness and the protocol involved.

Comment: LR VUGen: 11.0.0, LR Controller 11.03 (used both as Controller and Loadgenerator), with patch 1,2,3 for LR11.0. Windows Server 2008-R2 Standard. 4 GB RAM, 64-bits OS. Web Service Protocol in VUGen.

Comment: Strange... Did you try the support forum? http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/LoadRunner-Support-Forum/bd-p/sws-LoadRunner_SF#.Ugd-6ZI3A_I

Answer (score 0):

What is the state of application. Can you please try increasing the heap size of application.

Do you see the similar problem with vugen as well or is this only happening with controller

Comment: It only happens after typically 30 minutes in stable state running in the controller, and it is siginificant what size I choose for the attachments. With 250 kb it does not happen, but with 3 Mb attachments it does happen.